# Types of argon gas regulator?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, equipment

I have a high pressure bottle of argon gas (99.98 %) that I need to use in an experiment. The problem is that the regulator I have is a generic type that is seemingly optimized for high flow rates (welding). I need a fairly low flow rate of under 200 cm³/min. However, I do not know what kind of regulator would be suitable. Any suggestions for search description?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about chemistry.

Comment: @Jan Disagree. I used 200sccm flows of argon in some of the experiments in my chemical engineering Ph.D. work.  Knowledge/use of the proper gas handling equipment was important. Thought experiment: Replace $\ce{Ar}$ with a non-inert gas like $\ce{SO2}$ or $\ce{Cl2}$ -- still off-topic?

Comment: This is used as part of chem eng PhD work by a student at Imperial College London

Comment: @Brian imho yes.

Comment: So discussing equipment used in chem labs is off topic?

Comment: @Jan Interesting... under what discipline *would* you file it? No others immediately come to mind.

Comment: @Brian some engineering something. The question is about the pressure regulator if I read it correctly. Much like I would not consider it on-topic here to ask for how to repair vacuum pumps. It is simply lacking the direct connection to chemistry that it would require imho. Three others agreed with me.

Comment: Would how to get a gas tight seal on an Erlenmeyer flask be similarly off topic?

Comment: @Jan No, I see your point: the scope addressed by the question is much broader than just chemistry.  However, in the definition of [tag:equipment], it says right up front "This tag should be applied to questions that are about the equipment used in labs, and techniques of keeping them, their uses, or their maintenance."  That gas regulators &c. are used many other places does not negate the fact that they are also used in labs. But, I can see it going either way--in the end, I will be content with the decision of the community.

Comment: For the sake of full disclosure: I do not think it is off topic here and hence I hesitated to act on the raised flag. It should be noted, that there was a [request in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24982853#24982853). Please also consider [this reply](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24994964#24994964). I stand by my word and I am now considering migration. Please make yourself heard with reasons why this should not be done. One option would be to open a discussion in [meta] or simply reply here. (cc @Brian) [OP: If you want migration please flag.]

Comment: also cc @Jan (may the 15 char threshold be with me)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Migration to Engineering.SE is an acceptable resolution to me. Nick Alexeev's point about the possibility for additional perspective is a good one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No cylinder regulator that I know of will provide fine control of flow rates on the order you require.  The purpose of a regulator is to control the line pressure, not the line flow rate.  In theory you could stick a [flowmeter](http://www.mcmaster.com/#flow-rate-meters/=zjqa0q) in-line and try to finesse the regulator pressure and shutoff valve (if there even is one) to reach the flow you want, but it would probably be a maddening exercise.

What you need is a [mass flow controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_controller) (MFC) of some kind.  Depending on your budget and your needs for adjustability and precision of the flow rate, there is a variety of options:

- If you know you will only require a specific, set flow rate (or, a small number of set flow rates) you might do okay with a [flow orifice](http://www.mcmaster.com/#flow-control-orifices/=zjqakq): set the upstream pressure appropriately and the flow should match the spec.
- If you need to be able to vary the flow rate and an approximate value is acceptable, something like these [dial-knob flow control valves](http://www.mcmaster.com/#air-flow-control-valves/=zjqbg3) would probably work okay.
- If you need precise control of the flow rate, you're probably up against something like these [Porter mass flow controllers](http://www.porterinstrument.com/mass_flowc.php). They're quite pricey (a few thousand USD) but they work extremely well.  You'd need both the in-line MFC unit and the separate control box to make it work.

**IMPORTANT:** One thing to be aware of is that all of these technologies are gas-specific to a greater or lesser extent.  The orifices and dial-knob controllers depend at least on the viscosity and density of the gas, and the Porter MFCs depend also on the specific heat of the gas.  The differences will be minor, so I wouldn't worry about it for the first two, but if you need highly precise flow rates, you will have to compensate for the differences if you should need to switch gases.  Porter actually calibrates each MFC to a specific gas, so if you only need argon flows, you'll be all set.

Comment: No problem. I found someone who knew about this stuff and they got some bits and pieces from around the lab and fixed it for me. Part of the original problem turned out to be a faulty regulator. When that was replaced and a flow controller put inline it did the job.

Comment: @DirkBruere Heh, yeah - if the membrane in your regulator's blown, say, that'll definitely mean a lot more flow than you want. :-)